# After a company declares partnership, when does the quarter revenue start counting?

Tags: stocks

Is it the next quarter, or was the payment delivered in the same quarter?

Example: Yesterday AMD declared partnership with Microsoft saying that the new Surface 3 laptops will be delivered with AMD processor on board. Will the first revenues from that deal account for Q3 or Q4?

Comment: If you’re asking for specific provisions of the contract, I doubt either company will be willing to supply the information to unrelated parties.

Comment: @Lawrence Although AMD is mentioned, feel free to substitute any manufacturer or contract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AMD would record revenue whenever MS actually orders the AMD processors. They might have already done that, or they might not do that until next quarter. Unless either company states specifically when that is going to happen, there's no way to know for sure.

In general, a company records revenue whenever a purchase is made, or an order for a purchase is placed with a certain degree of reliability. Since just *declaring* a partnership does not generate revenue, the revenue would not be recorded until a purchase or order (e.g. for inventory or services) of some kind is actually made.

Comment: I believe the company I worked for (albeit selling software not hardware) couldn't declare revenue until "goods" (including services, in our case) were delivered and invoices issued, not simply when orders were placed. However, that's probably overly-splitting hairs. Your main point – that a partnership in itself doesn't generate revenue – still stands.

Comment: @TripeHound Yeah the "certain degree of reliability" may have applied there. If specific pricing is not agreed upon upfront then invoicing may be a reasonable time to record revenue.

Comment: Could it be the case that chips & other components that are used in assembly are delivered beforehand? In this particular case the laptops are shipped in three weeks, which would leave MS quite a time frame to set things going. I initially assumed that all chips & hardware should had been shipped to MS months before public availability. So the revenue would account for current quarter

Comment: Sure that's entirely possible. It's also possible that they ordered them a month ago and it would be in their 3Q revenue. It's also possible that they won't order the chips until January so it will show up in 1Q revenue next year (I have no idea what the product release timing is). The point is that you don't know for certain just based on an announcement without those specific details mentioned.